# Overlapping image and text in css with link on image only

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I am trying to make a new banner image for my website where the banner text hovers over a banner image and the banner image is a link. The banner text does not have a link. I am trying to make this banner work in a responsive layout as well. I previously used a combination of block and positioning elements but I am trying to implement a more elegant solution using css grid or flexbox.

**My old code:**

```css
header {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

header img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

header a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

h1 {
  font: normal 2.8em "verdana", sans-serif;
  color: #ddd;
  position: absolute;
  right: 2vw;
  bottom: 4vh;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a href="index"><img src="https://www.placebear.com/800/200" alt="Banner Image" /></a>
  <h1>website title</h1>
</header>
```

**New attempted code (flexbox + background-image method):**

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  height: 10vh;
  background-image: url("https://www.placebear.com/800/200");
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 2rem 0;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

h1 {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  line-height: 1.1em;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 4rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="index">
  <header>
    <h1>
      example text
    </h1>
  </header>
</a>
```

The problem I am having is that the link tag cannot apply to *just* the image in the flexbox + background-image method. The text is included as well, which is not what I am after.

**New attempted code (grid + link):**

```css
header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

header img {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

header p {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://www.placebear.com/800/200"></a>
  <p>SOME TEXT OVER IMAGE</p>
</header>
```

The grid + link method doesn't work because the link tag breaks the grid and forces itself to create another grid element below the banner image.

I am really drawing at straws here to figure out how to implement this properly. If anyone has any advice that would be awesome. Thanks a ton!

Comment: in your grid solution, simply make the `a` the grid item and it should be fine

Comment: I just tried this and it worked. Wow. I can't believe I missed something so simple! Thanks for your input. I think that'll work for my purposes :D

Comment: @commissioneranthony I misinterpreted the question entirely (and have deleted my answer). Out of curiousity, while the grid solution would work, I'm wondering why you would want to have the header function in this way?

Comment: Hi Rachel. No worries! I wanted the banner of my website to have an image and I wanted the title to be selectable so someone could highlight the title, copy and paste and reuse it as they please. To me, having text locked behind an image is like having a pdf you can't edit. It's a superbly minor issue at best and more of a pet peeve. Thanks for your input though!